# Passing command to erl?

Tags: erlang, erl

We are running an erlang program (ejabberd). Sometimes, we need to do health checks by connecting an erl shell to this running erlang program.

I am trying to script all this, and rather than typing `erl -sname r -remsh ....` and then, my command in the erlang shell, I'm looking for way to directly execute that command from my bash shell and get the output. Is this possible?

After Odobenus's answer, I wrote this little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -sname r -setcookie `cat ~ejabberd/.erlang.cookie`

main([]) -> 
    Res = rpc:call(ejabberd@xmpp,mnesia,info,[]),
    io:format("~p~n",[Res]).
```

The problem is that I get a "Node Down" Error, even though these are the exact same params I use to connect with `erl`: `` erl -sname r -remsh ejabberd@xmpp -setcookie `cat ~ejabberd/.erlang.cookie` ``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write escript for that purpose http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/escript.html

kind of (for example tst.erl)

```
#!/usr/bin/env escript
%%! -sname r 

main([Cookie]) -> 
    erlang:set_cookie(node(),list_to_atom(Cookie)),
    Res = rpc:call(name@somenode,somemodule,somefunction,[]),
    io:format("~p~n",[Res]).
```

and call it from bash script

```
./tst.erl `cat verythatfile`
```

Comment: Unfortunately, i do get a `{badrpc,nodedown}`. The thing is thaat when I connect with erl, I use remsh, which I can't seem to be able to do with escript. Any idea?

Comment: nodedown means escript doesnt see your server. Did you set the same cookies?

Comment: Dang, my `cat ~ejabberd/.erlang.cookie` fails in thge %% line. Entering it manually solved that problem... However it would nice to avoid that. Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in -sname parameter. Use full name -name node@host and everything will work